# jQuery. Insert one object into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert one DOM object into another with jQuery. The first object is a set of three div's and the second object is an empty div. When i pass first object as a parameter to html() method applied to second object i get a type error: "undefined is not a function".

```
var itemContent = $("selector for the first object");
var itemTarget = $("selector for the second object");
itemTarget.html(itemContent);
```

I think there is something wrong with the type of parameter that i pass to html() method. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `itemTarget.empty().append(itemContent);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny But it is as same as `.html()`...

Comment: itemTarget.html(itemContent.html()); ?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but as per spec .html() accepts a string not a jQuery object

Comment: @ArunPJohny I though so too, but http://jsfiddle.net/bbYb8/....

Comment: @ArunPJohny and also see this http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/c6g8h/1/.. that was not specified in the DOCS..

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it will work... I was pointing to the fact that as per spec that is not what is expected... using undocumented features of any library is dangerous as it might get changed any time without advance notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should get the HTML of the first container**

```
var itemContent = $("selector for the first object").html(),
     itemTarget = $("selector for the second object");
     itemTarget.html(itemContent);
```

Documentation for jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Happy codding!!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass direct object into HTML, if you want to pass the content of first container to the second container, then you can use the below method

```
var itemContent = $("selector for the first object").html();

var itemTarget = $("selector for the second object");

itemTarget.html(itemContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("selector for the second object").append($("selector for the first object").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to **move** DOM element is using functions like http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ .  If you're making something with HTML - you're losing all events and data of this DOM element. 
Read about this function especially this text:

We can also select an element on the page and insert it after another:

```
$( "h2" ).insertAfter( $( ".container" ) );
```

If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved after the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned:

Comment: Little fix: Use append function :)